# Spring hibernate JPA One to many mapping:Duplicate key error

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have  one to many relationships between the following 2 entities.

```
@Entity
    public class OrderItem {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_PRODUCT_ID")
        private Product product;
        private Long quantity;
        private BigDecimal totalPrice;
        @OneToMany
        @JoinTable(name="orderItem_productaddition",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="orderItem_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ProductAddition_id"))
        private Set<ProductAddition> listOfAdditions=new HashSet<>();
        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(unique = true)
        private ProductOption productOption;
    }
```

Second Entity

```
@Entity
public class ProductAddition{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String additionDescription;
    private BigDecimal additionPrice;
    private BigDecimal additionsPriceForSmall;
    private BigDecimal additionsPriceForNormal;
    private BigDecimal additionsPriceForFamily;
    private BigDecimal additionsPriceForParty;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "productAdditions")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Product>product=new HashSet<>();
}
```

Following is the existing data in the join table order_item_productaddition.

[image]

For following insert  i get the
**Duplicate entry '41' for key 'UK_22djpp3b17x2x1vurh26crns'**

insert into website_dev.order_item_productaddition values(379,41)

I do not understand what is wrong with my Join table mapping, it is one to many relationships and i expect  multiple entries.
why does spring jpa adds unique key constraint to the join table.
Is there any way to make composite key constraint in Join table ? or how can i remove the constraint ?

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add more details about your Schema? It is difficult to understand

Comment: You've a Unique Key for column `product_addition_id` and since `41` is already present in the `order_item_productaddition` table

Comment: @Mansoor ofcouse its already present but in my data model it should be possible.I expect same addition for multiple product.

Comment: spring hibernate generates the schema.there is nothing extra to these 2 tables.

Comment: The error you are getting is because of Unique Key Constraint Violation. Which means, your **table** has a unique key constraint. 
Did you generate your tables/schema from Entities? Can you check in your schema if you've unique key constraint in the `order_item_productaddition` table

Comment: yes. i am generating my schema from entities.please check the orderItem entity.  i am using @Join table annotation. there is no extra entity for the order_item_productaddition table.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a ManyToMany instead of OneToMany

Comment: @SB since you have mentioned. it seems like i had a problem thinking it through. you are right.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use "insert" rather than JPA persist or merge?